# Is there a way to COMMIT the work when a running script is canceled

Tags: oracle

I have running a script in Oracle for 3 days but it has not finished.

My script does not have COMMIT command, unfortunately. If I cancel it, the total result of my script is rollback.

I want commit the result of script now and finally cancel it.
Is there a solution for my problem?

Comment: Need more info - Do you have access to the Oracle's session on which the script runs _after_ cancelling the session? If yes, you may have a chance. Does the script contains multiple statements or a single query is taking long? If multiple statements, then you may have a chance to partially commit the statements that have completed so far. If it is single, then you are out of luck as Oracle's transactions are atomic (ie., ACID compliant). Also you need to make sure, your script resumes from where it left next time you run to ensure data consistency and avoid a rerun.

Comment: Personally I would be more concerned with a script running _that_ long. I would find the root cause, see if there are any locks and tune if necessary by the wait events.

Comment: You might like to check for long operations running in the database, although ironically the type of operation that the database monitors as "long" is often not the type that causes performance problems of this type. I suspect that you have an over-reliance on row-by-row PL/SQL processing, based on index driven access.