# commit for any of record in oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, query-optimization

I have a script that is taking a long time to update 60 million records. Here's the query:

```
UPDATE baseinformation w
SET good_item_id = (SELECT id FROM item e WHERE e.id = w.id)
```

My problem: I want to commit for any record when that query is running. I would like to commit any changed records in SQL from another session. My problem is solved in PLSQL by `LOOP`. Is there a solution or command in pure Oracle SQL for my goal?

Comment: How long take? Do you have index on both tables `id` ?

Comment: You definitely need indexes on item.id and baseinformation.good_item_id for the above to have any sort of decent performance.

Comment: PLSQL is not the right choice here. When you are able to do it in a single SQL, you _should_ do it in a single SQL. The right solution is to understand _why_ the SQL is running slowly and tune it. Are the stats on both tables up-to-date? Are there any contention issues?  Any indexes, triggers on the table `baseinformation` which might slow down the update, etc.,

Comment: Is it possible to write the query with out the subquery in Oracle (i.e. using a join instead of the subquery)? This might give better performance.

Answer (score 3):

A couple of us advised you [in your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32535342/146325) that you should try to solve the performance issue by tuning the SQL statement rather than seeking to subvert the transaction's integrity. Now you have posted the update we are in a position to help you do that.

The thing about UPDATE is that it is just a variant of SELECT: the database has to find rows before it can change them.  So we often we can reduce the execution time by tuning the access path.  For instance, we can run EXPLAIN PLAN for update statements:

```
explain plan for
    UPDATE baseinformation w
    SET good_item_id = (SELECT id FROM item e WHERE e.id = w.id)
/
```

Without access to your Explain Plan, stats and data skews it is difficult to offer hard advice.  On the face of it your statement will execute one read on `item` for *each row* in `baseinformation`.  Even if the access is  INDEX UNIQUE SCAN,  60 million of them is a lot of reads.  If there are rows in `baseinformation` which don't have a matching `id` in `item` it gets more expensive still.  As @DavidAldridge commented the database could still implement a more efficient path but if your statement has been running for three days it seems it hasn't made a good decision.

So what you need to do is help the optimizer make a better decision.  One obvious thing is to make sure the database statistics are accurate, for both the tables and any indexes they have.

Another thing is to convert those individual lookups into a set operation, which should give a more efficient access path.  Your SQL as presented updates `baseinformation.good_item_id` to `item.id` if `item.id` matches `baseinformation.id`.  So this statement is logically equivalent ...

```
update baseinformation w
set w.good_item_id = w.id
where w.id in ( select e.id from item e)
/
```

... as is this one ...

```
update baseinformation w
set w.good_item_id = w.id
where exists ( select e.id from item e where e.id = w.id )
/
```

If `baseinformation` has a huge number of rows and `item` has a tiny number of matching rows then the WHERE ... IN formulation is the better approach.  If `baseinformation` is tiny and `item` is huge then the WHERE EXISTS ... formulation will probably perform better.  If both tables are roughly eqivalent in the number of rows than either approach might be better, depending on indexes, clustering, etc so you'll need to benchmark both.

Another approach would be to execute a join of the two tables.  You could do so  with a MERGE statement ...

```
merge into baseinformation w
  using ( select id from item ) e
  on (e.id = w.id)
when matched then 
  update 
  set w.good_item_id = e.id
/
```

... or with an updateable in-line view ...

```
update (
        select 
            e.id as item_id
            , w.good_item_id 
        from baseinformation w
             join item e
             on (e.id = w.id)
)
set good_item_id = item_id
/
```

Probably these will have similar performance profiles to the sub-queries, but again indexing strategies or data skew might favour one over the rest.

---

To actually address your question :)

> "Is there a solution or command in pure Oracle SQL"

No.  SQL statements are atomic.  There is no way to commit an increment of the UPDATE statement.  You could restrict the UPDATE to an artificial subset of rows e.g.

```
update baseinformation w
set w.good_item_id = w.id
where w.id in ( select e.id from item e)
and w.good_item_id is null
and rownum <= 20000
/
```

We could use such a statement in a PL/SQL block to update and commit chunks of twenty thousand rows.  However this will result in a longer elapsed time, because you'll be continually kicking off a FULL TABLE SCAN of `baseinformation`.  Also, this approach causes problems with transactional consistency: any session querying `baseinformation` on the basis of `good_item_id` will get a potentially misleading result set.

The only advantage of incremental commits is that it gives us a recovery point if the updating process fails for any reason.  This is not a negligible advantage with a long-running process, but the top priority should be to tackle the "long-running" aspect.

As for committing from another session, that is not possible.  Oracle imposes a Read Committed isolation level.  That means that sessions can only see changed records after the changing session has committed the changes.  There are no dirty reads in Oracle.  This means one session cannot commit changes in another session.  [Find out more](http://docs.oracle.com/database/121/CNCPT/consist.htm#CNCPT621).

Comment: "your statement will execute one read on item for each row in baseinformation" -- are you sure? It could be transformed to an outer join, and implemented as a hash join.

Comment: @DavidAldridge - you're right, I'm not sure.  The OP's previous question stated that the query had been running for three days, from which I guessed they had a very sub-optimal access path.  I'll edit my answer to clarify that.

Answer (score 0):

You should understand that the `update` statement you are using is atomic. It can only be `commit`ted after the statement as a whole executes successfully i.e. updating `baseinformation` table in your case. A `commit` can not be issued for each record updated. This is to enable consistency in the database so other users don't see bad records when you perform the `update`. If an error occurs during the process, the transaction is rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to do this by adding a limit clause in the sql.  The query should return the number of rows updated.  Set up a while loop in the calling code and call the query with the limit clause until it returns 0.  Something like this (this is off the top of my head and might not be the exact syntax for Oracle)

```
update baseinformation w 
set good_item_id = 
  (select id from item e where e.id = w.id 
   and e.id != w.id 
   and ROWNUM <= 1000);
```

Comment: Two `WHERE` clauses in the same SELECT statement are not valid.

Answer (score -1):

Do you really need to update every record every time?  You could do something like this:

```
update baseinformation w 
set good_item_id = (select id from item e where e.id = w.id 
and e.id != w.id)
```

Comment: This SQL isn't even valid (How do you access alias "e" outside the subquery?).

Answer (score -2):

Reason for taking time is there might be indexes on the column(s) which will consume more time. If you try removing indexes and execute, it might work. Also once you start executing the lock on the record will be hold to your session until you commit. So, you cannot execute the statement in another session.